# How to list my categories and forums related to it? Django

Tags: django

### Model

```
class Category(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

    cat_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()

    def get_forums(self):
        get_forum = Forum.objects.filter(category=self)
        return get_forum

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.cat_name}"

class Forum(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        verbose_name_plural = "Forums"

    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="forums")
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    forum_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.forum_name}"
```

---

### Views

```
class Home(ListView):
    model = Category
    template_name = 'forums/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'category'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['cat'] = Category.objects.all()
        return context
```

---

### HTML

```
{% block content %}
{% for cat in category %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="bg-success rounded-top border border-dark" style="width:100%; padding-left:8px;">
                {{cat.cat_name}}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="bg-secondary border border-dark" style="width:100%; padding-left:16px;">
           Forums_Go_Here
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

---

I am trying to get a homepage where I would be able to list my categories and show the forums in those categories. 
The template I have is running a for loop which is looping through all Categories.
In the shell i am able to get the forums with the: Category.objects.get(pk=2).get_forums() command. But this limits it to one category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use related name for that, no need to use additional method:

```
{% block content %}
{% for cat in category %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="bg-success rounded-top border border-dark" style="width:100%; padding-left:8px;">
                {{cat.cat_name}}
        </div>
    </div>
    {% for forum in cat.forums.all %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="bg-secondary border border-dark" style="width:100%; padding-left:16px;">
               {{forum.forum_name}}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor%}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Also you have a mistake there:

```
context['category'] = Category.objects.all()
```

If you want to access it as `category` in template put it there with that key, not `cat`.